# How to make content fill all the screen?

Tags: android

How to make content fill all the screen regardless of screen size?

Images are below.
I want it look like the left image, **NOT** like the right:

[image] [image]

Comment: what this , listview or what?

Comment: This is in relative layout and there are 3 textviews and 6 buttons

Comment: put all this view in one Realative Layout and make its height , width like that android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: @minafawzy since fill_parent has been **deprecated**, you'd better use **match_parent**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use RelativeLayout you can change your container to LinearLayout and set layout_weight to its children:

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text 1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let consider that your XML file

create inner RelativeLayout and set its width and height to match_parent

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp" >
<!-- here you create your RelativeLayout -->
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/reminder" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dates"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/name"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@id/times"
      android:layout_width="96dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/name"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
   <Button
      android:layout_width="96dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/times"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:text="@string/done" />

<!-- here close of your created RelativeLayout -->
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```